# seachable qcombobox only giving me 1 result

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox, searchable-dropdown

I'm trying to make a searchable combo box. Right now it searches it, but will only give me 1 result and I have to type in the whole item in the list for it to edit the list to only include the resulted item. I'm trying to get it where if I have multiple results in the editable but not insertable combo box, that it will give me every result in the combo box, even if I only type in a partial match. For example if I type in "200" it will give me all the items that contain anywhere in it "200" and then afterwards if I type in "100" it will give me a whole different list of items to choose from but the list now contains "100" anywhere in the items instead of the previous "200".

Sample of my list

```
    self.Part = ["200019359", "300000272", "300000275", "200018792", "10024769", "10015919", "102000765"]
```

My function

```
    def PartNumber(self):
    if self.PartNum.currentText() != "" :
        results =  [s for s in self.Part if self.PartNum.currentText() in s]
        self.PartNum.clear()
        self.PartNum.addItems(results)
    else:
        self.PartNum.clear()
        self.PartNum.addItems(self.Part)
```

Connecting it to the combo box

```
    self.PartNum.activated.connect(self.PartNumber)
```

Comment: Using `activated()` is not correct, as it's only triggered when an item is actually selected (from the drop down list, or by pressing enter in an editable combo). Also, clearing the items every time is not a valid idea, because if you then clear the text, the items won't be restored. Why don't you use a [QCompleter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) instead? `self.PartNum.setCompleter(QCompleter(self.Part))`

Comment: Thank you that worked. I'm still fairly new to python, and coding in general, and didn't know about the qcompiler. I'll have to add the qcompiler to my study material to see what else it does.

Comment: Note, it's **QCompleter**, not QCompiler, be more careful with terminology. Qt classes always have very descriptive names, in this case you're using an [auto *completion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete) (similar to what we normally use in smartphone virtual keyboards). Also, remember that only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not variables, functions or attributes: you should change to `self.part`, `self.partNum` and `partNumber()`, but, even better, you should use more *descriptive* names, as right now the above are too similar: for instance, `partCombo`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to take your time and read the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). Since you're new to programming, be aware that one of the most important (and underestimated) aspects is *readability*, which is also one of the fundamental aspects on which python has been created. Writing code that can be easily read (and, thus, understood) is extremely important, as it improves both coding and debugging, but it's also really helpful whenever you need to read other's code (including your own, if you read it weeks or months after writing it).